# How can I display an image on VS Code and PyCharm?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I want to choose the best IDE for Python programming so I'm testing different softwares but I have problem.

When I try this code blocks on VS Code I don't see any error but the image is not showing

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image = mpimg.imread('exit-ramp.jpg')
plt.imshow(image)
```

[VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S50S7.png)

When I try run the same code on PyCharm I see some errors

[PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVAow.png)

But when I run the same code on Jupyter Notebook it works. What can I do?

Answer (score 9):

Bro, try that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image = mpimg.imread('exit-ramp.jpg')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

i've made a test in my vscode.

Few weeks ago i used a lot pycharm... but i get some library errors with pandas and pycharm its a little bit heavy.

VSCODE its light and i didnt get any library error that i had with pycharm.

Comment: Hey! It works now but I didn't understand why worked on Jupyter Notebook but didn't work on VS Code. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @BatuhanTastekin. I'm a developer on the VSCode Python extension. I'm glad this is working for you now, but I don't believe that using plt.show() should be needed in general. I'm worried that we might have bug here. Would you mind if I asked you a quick question?
Did you by any change change any matplotlib settings? Our tool works like the "Plotting from an IPython notebook" section here.
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.00-introduction-to-matplotlib.html#show()-or-No-show()?-How-to-Display-Your-Plots

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your code -> Run current file in interactive window.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a backend problem to be changed in matplotlib. If you start your Python shell whether you are in a bash shell or in vscode, you should use a backend that will show the plot. Otherwise the *plt.show()* call is required.

So, one solution is to change the backend either manually in you Python shell or when starting the Python shell as explained here below.

Note, however, that I always use the qt5 backend but got the same issue as yours: no plot appears. I changed to the **Qt5Agg** backend and it worked for me (providing PyQt5 is installed).

So, first solution, you can try to set the backend when starting the Python shell:

```
ipython --pylab Qt5Agg
```

You should use a GUI backend amongst the possible backend. If you do not known, try to replace **Qt5Agg** by  **auto**

The second solution consists in changing the backend manually once in the Python shell:

```
import matplotlib as plt
plt.use('Qt5Agg')
```