# Why are the Images not available if I run the program through VS Code instead of PyCharm?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

Used Images don't show up while I use VS Code, but everywhere else the Images are there.

I wrote my first Program in PyCharm and if I run the program on PyCharm the Images used will show up as they should. I drag and dropped the same .py file into VS Code, picked my Python interpreter and there aren't any problems. But the implented pictures only show up if I run the program with PyCharm or double-click the .py in the folder.

While the .py file is opened in VS Code and i hover over the file in the upper bar, the shown directory is the one where I drag and dropped it from into VS Code, in this same folder are also the used Images.

Why does VS Code don't show the Images and how can I fix this? It will run the program and I can also interact normally with the program, beside the missing Pictures/Icons.

I used PyQt5 for this program and this is the Code for the Frame which is in the program and the picture I implemented in this Frame:

````
```python
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Dialog)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(35, 170, 257, 171))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 257, 171))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("essen.png"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
```
````

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. The code should be a [mre].

Comment: The most likely reason for this behavior is that PyCharm and VSCode are running your program from different directories. If you've referenced the images in your code as relative paths, this could cause the images to not appear on one of the IDEs. Check your VSCode settings to make sure it's running your code from the same folder as PyCharm.

Comment: sounds related but potentially different issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58779759/11107541

Comment: Thank you MattDMo for your insight and your tips. I did some mistakes all around creating this question and hopefully the next questions will be more clear overall. 
I was not able to check how VSCode can run the code from the same folder as PyCharm, but I thought about it and after opening the whole folder with the Images and the .py file, VSCode can start the program and show me the Images. 
Beside the fact that the Code should be visible in the Text rather than in a picture(actually I dont think the Code is even necesseray anymore), what else was misunderstanding in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vscode takes the currently opened folder as the workspace, you'd better put your code script and your picture file in the same directory.

Or you can use an absolute path to indicate the image location in the code.